# Should reCaptcha V3 work with automation frameworks like cypress?

Tags: recaptcha, cypress, recaptcha-v3

I'm currently migrating an application from reCAPTCHA V2 to V3. I'm using cypress (cypress.io) automation framework to test a signup page. I'm surprised that after implementing it, even with reCAPTCHA V3 turned on, all my test cases passed. It was getting a scope of 0.9.

Is this expected or could is reCAPTCHA V3 to work with these types of automation or is this an unsolved vulnerability with V3? I don't think I'll want to continue with V3 if something like this can easily pass the reCAPTCHA.

I followed the following guides to implement recaptcha

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CsqbN-ZrCbc

Comment: Cypress re-uses the same browser session between tests, just clearing out the localStorage and cookies which it's aware of. Without know reCAPTCHA's algorithm, it's hard to say, but maybe Cypress has done enough interaction with your site through tests that Google thinks it's actually a user

Comment: This is still in local development so the website would be localhost. From what I can tell now the V3 relies, as you said, on a lot of context of interaction so maybe it's not built for one-of pages until a good amount of analytics data is created.